# Why are SQLite and MySQL not giving same result on subselect?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm using the [Chinook](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) test database to compare Sqlite3 and MySQL5 query results.

Can anyone tell me why the following query gives different results in these two databases, and why MySQL is creating a new InvoiceId?

```
SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE InvoiceDate > (SELECT AVG(InvoiceDate) FROM invoice) LIMIT 3
```

[image]

---

## addendum:

[image]

Comment: If you remove the `LIMIT` clause, is the result set the same with a different order? It most likely is, and the implementations have different ways of selecting rows.

Comment: I think you need an ORDER BY if you want the same three

Comment: @evan yes each database has different orders, interesting. Most interesting though is the MySQL lists the invoice ids incorrectly as shown above (the invoiceid for theordor... is 1, not 195, and sqlite gets it right) why is that?

Comment: @EdwardTanguay: You still have a `LIMIT` clause in your addendum. Therefore, the three results will be chosen at the implementation's discretion, since the `ORDER BY` will be run after the `LIMIT 3`. In other words, it chooses 3 rows and then orders them.

Comment: @evan, even if I retain the "order by" and remove the "limit 3" mysql still lists the invoiceid as e.g. 196 instead of the real value 1, and the order in sqlite and mysql are different.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay: Strange. (Also, after some research, it seems the ordering is done prior to the limiting, so my previous explanation is incorrect.) If you run your average invoiceDate query alone on both implementations, are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

the order of the result is unspecified; therefore which are "the first three" of them is unspecified too.

just because you got the same order on both engines when you didn't use a subselect, it doesn't mean they'll be the same always.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE InvoiceDate > (SELECT AVG(InvoiceDate) FROM invoice) ORDER BY InvoiceId ASC LIMIT 3

MySQL isn't creating a new invoice ID, it's simply not ordering the result set.

Comment: I tried that (see above), MySQL still lists the records with an InvoiceId that is incorrect, strange.

Comment: What does `SELECT AVG(InvoiceDate) FROM invoice` return? Is that different on both databases or the same?